# Turning off PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES what does it do?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm doing

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

because it's the way I found to receive data with it's native type from the database instead of only string, but what does it really do? Will it affect my prepared statements?

Answer (score 0):

PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES Enables or disables emulation of prepared statements. Some drivers do not support native prepared statements or have limited support for them. Use this setting to force PDO to either always emulate prepared statements (if TRUE), or to try to use native prepared statements (if FALSE). It will always fall back to emulating the prepared statement if the driver cannot successfully prepare the current query. Requires bool.

for more attribute set , http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php